# How do I clean my boot partion using a live cd

Tags: boot

I have an upgrade install of Ubuntu 16.04.1 which will not load the desktop, when I attempt some of the solutions I get an error
gzip: stdout: No space left on device.
My /boot partition is 449 MB and has many old kernel versions.
I am currently using a Live CD while searching for solutions, how can
I free up some space on the /boot partition?

Here is the output of a ls command on the mounted boot partition in a live cd session:

```
abi-3.13.0-67-generic
abi-3.13.0-68-generic
abi-3.13.0-70-generic
abi-3.13.0-71-generic
abi-3.13.0-73-generic
abi-3.13.0-74-generic
abi-3.13.0-76-generic
abi-3.13.0-77-generic
abi-3.13.0-79-generic
abi-3.13.0-83-generic
abi-3.13.0-88-generic
abi-3.13.0-91-generic
abi-3.13.0-92-generic
abi-4.4.0-31-generic
config-3.13.0-67-generic
config-3.13.0-68-generic
config-3.13.0-70-generic
config-3.13.0-71-generic
config-3.13.0-73-generic
config-3.13.0-74-generic
config-3.13.0-76-generic
config-3.13.0-77-generic
config-3.13.0-79-generic
config-3.13.0-83-generic
config-3.13.0-88-generic
config-3.13.0-91-generic
config-3.13.0-92-generic
config-4.4.0-31-generic
grub
initrd.img-3.13.0-67-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-68-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-70-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-71-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-73-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-76-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-77-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-79-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-83-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-88-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-91-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-92-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
lost+found
memtest86+.bin
memtest86+.elf
memtest86+_multiboot.bin
System.map-3.13.0-67-generic
System.map-3.13.0-68-generic
System.map-3.13.0-70-generic
System.map-3.13.0-71-generic
System.map-3.13.0-73-generic
System.map-3.13.0-74-generic
System.map-3.13.0-76-generic
System.map-3.13.0-77-generic
System.map-3.13.0-79-generic
System.map-3.13.0-83-generic
System.map-3.13.0-88-generic
System.map-3.13.0-91-generic
System.map-3.13.0-92-generic
System.map-4.4.0-31-generic
vmlinuz-3.13.0-67-generic
vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic
vmlinuz-3.13.0-70-generic
vmlinuz-3.13.0-71-generic
vmlinuz-3.13.0-73-generic
vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
vmlinuz-3.13.0-77-generic
vmlinuz-3.13.0-79-generic
vmlinuz-3.13.0-83-generic
vmlinuz-3.13.0-88-generic
vmlinuz-3.13.0-91-generic
vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
```

Comment: What does it show when you boot normally?

Comment: The background image and the mouse pointer only, no side bar or menu

Comment: Can you do normal boot,  press Ctrl+Alt+F1, login with your user to console and try command `sudo apt-get autoremove` ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your system is booting up (though not in GUI), you can remove old kernels using tty. To do so, follow these steps.

- After booting the system (where you see the cursor and blank screen), switch to tty by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + F1`.
- Enter your username and password.
- Run this command to check out the current kernel. `uname -r`. Do not remove this kernel in the next steps. This is just a safety measure.
- Next run this command `dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+' | grep -Fv $(uname -r)`. This command lists all the kernels excluding the current kernel.
- Remove all kernels starting with `ii` using the command `sudo dpkg --purge kernel-name`. For example `sudo dpkg--purge linux-image-4.4.0-21`. If the command failes, then remove the dependency packages that are mentioned in the output the same way i.e. `sudo dpkg --purge PACKAGE`.
- Also try to remove the respective header using the command `sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-header linux-image`. The header must correspond to the kernel being removed. This means that if the kernel removed is linux-image-4.4.0-21 then the header would be linux-image-4.4.0-21-header. It is ok even if this command fails.
- Finally, fix the broken dependencies using`sudo apt install -f`

Comment: The command that lists all the kernels has no output, is there a way to do this using a live cd, as i can copy and paste commands and post any results here

Comment: Try the command without the following part. | grep -Fv $(uname -r). If the command lists only one kernel that means that there is no old kernel. Also, in order to avoid errors, do copy the command instead of typing it.

Comment: Thank you for answers, i have tried your suggestion and there is only one kernel. I can mount the boot partition using a live cd session and post the output of a file listing, to show what files are taking up space. My mistake was assuming there were old kernels.

Comment: I added a file list of the contents of /boot to my question, sorry it is hard to read

Comment: Please start a new question since the issue is different than the one posted in above question. Post a link to the question here so that I can help. Also if this answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as selected.

Comment: Here is a link to a new question http://askubuntu.com/questions/809537/how-do-i-free-up-some-space-on-boot-partition-using-a-live-cd-session

Comment: I deleted all the files in boot except for the latest versions, did not have any luck when trying solutions, so I have solved the problem with a reinstall